# How to Unlink a Work or School account in B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm looking for an example of how to unlink an Azure Work/School account from a B2C user.  I've used this sample policy [Account-Linkage-Unified](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/account-linkage-unified) and can successfully link a Work/School account, but the unlinking uses the below Metadata tag to find the entry in the "identities" collection to present the Unlink button... but a work/school account's Issuer is *[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant) Id}/*v2.0**

```html
<Metadata>
  <Item Key="ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable">login.microsoftonline.com</Item>
</Metadata>
```

I need a way to have this match the value pulled back from the identities collection if it matches "login.microsoftonline.com".

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You can refer this Microsoft Documentation link regarding technical profiles, in which in the last part of this documentation, it is specified that 'ClaimValueonWhichToEnable' is to be passed with 'OnItemExistenceInStringCollectionClaim': -https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/account-linkage-unified. Please refer it and check whether it is  helpful.

Comment: Hi, your link is to the custom policy I am using.   The issue is OnItemExistenceInStringCollectionClaim works, but it's a static representation based on the Meta tag I posted above ... whereas I need it to match the dynamic result of an actual issuer for another Azure tenant that is in the user's identities collection.  Not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom attribute in which to place the issuer value in (https://login.microsoftonline.com/3b7daec3-d31c-xxxx-b5d4-e6e5facd1080/v2.0), so that when unlinking, the technical profile can pull this from the user and find the correct identity in the collection to remove.